# Bound on number of steps needed for points to meet enclosing convex polygon

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, asymptotics, recreational-mathematics

Let $P$ be the set of equidistant points on the unit circle which are then randomly shuffled. They then take discrete steps towards the midpoint between the 2 points that they were originally adjacent to along a curve analogous to a [pursuit curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pursuit_curve).

The illustration below shows a black line joining each point with its adjacent pair for $|P|=200$. The red curve is the points' enclosing convex polygon:

[image]

[code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinq321/pursuit/master/convex_hull)

What is a lower bound on the number of steps needed for each point to touch its enclosing curve? Empirically it seems like $O(k^2 /\log k)$ where $k=|P|,$ but I have no idea why this might be, or even whether it is at all.

This is a special case of [this question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2427050/staff-icebreaker-is-stasis-ever-attained).

Comment: IN what sense is the resultant closed curve the projection of a knot?  It does look like a jumbled string but it does not necessarily look like there was a knot in the string at first.

Comment: @MarkFischler will remove - not really helpful description!